# 100 households are surveyed, 60 have cats and 40 have dogs whilst 20 have neither a car or dog. How many households have only cats?

Tags: combinatorics

100 households are surveyed on a street.
60 have cats, 40 have dogs and 20 have neither a car or dog.
How many households have only a cat?

If you could please show all working out it would be appreciated.

Also (and I apologize if this is a dumb question) would it be possible to work this out using algebra?

Edit: I have attempted this and got 40 but I'm not 100 percent sure I'm correct.

Comment: Hint: Draw a Venn diagram and see if you can figure out the number of households in each part of the diagram

Comment: What have *you* tried? You're not going to get much of a (good) response posting what looks very much like a homework problem without any indication as to what you've already tried.

Comment: Your answer is correct . There are 40 with only cats, 20 with only dogs , 20 with both cats and dogs and 20 with neither of them. 40+20+20+20=100

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be the number of houses with only cats; $D$, only dogs; $B$, both; and $N$, none.

$\begin{align}C+B&=60\\
D+B&=40\\
N&=20\\
C+D+B+N&=100
\end{align}$

Now you have four equations and four equations, so it's easily solvable now. The answer will be $C$.

Comment: $C+D+B+N$ should be equal to 100

Comment: My mistake. I changed the naming of the variables in my mind when I was writing the answer.  Thanks a lot.